# How to create child object of existing super object, using JOINED inheritance strategy and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

what is the appropriate way how create child object of persisted super object with Hibernate?

Consider following example:
In database is persisted `User` with ID 1, firstName Kevin and laseName Smith. By the time is database model extended of new Entity `Auditor` which is child class of `User`. For inheritance is used strategy `JOINED`, so database model now has tow tables: *user* and *auditor*. These tables are jointed using user_id FK.

I would like create of Kevin Smith object type Auditor and persist. Problem is that operations are transactional and Hibernate throws `NonUniqueObjectException`. Exists any way how to safely cast persisted object do child object? I tried to evict given User object, but still the same.

**User entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class User{

    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**Auditor entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "auditor")
public class Auditor extends User {
  // some properties
}
```

**Logic**

> ```
> public void createAuditorOfUser(final long userId) {
>   final User user = userService.getUserById(userId);
>   // ...
>   final Auditor auditor = new Auditor();
>   auditor.setId(user.getId());
>   auditor.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
>   auditor.setLastName(user.getLastName());
>   userService.evict(user);
>   // will throw  NonUniqueObjectException
>   auditorService.update(auditor);
>   // ...
> }
> ```

I hope the problem is clear, if not I'll try improve description.

Comment: Add code when you got the exception. `NonUniqueObjectException` means a single session has multiple objects of same type in session with same identifier.

Comment: Try calling session.merge() before calling evict().

Comment: @Jack I did. Now it throws `StaleObjectStateException`: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)

Comment: Could you paste your service, dao and their config ?

Comment: @Pracede I solved given problem using NATIVE sql query insert to Auditor's table.

Answer (score 3):

I think Hibernate intentionally restrict such behaviour. Of course you can do it with native SQL workaround (as you already did).

In Java also we can't cast an object of super class to a sub-class then fill new fields of same object. Instead, create a new instance of sub-class then copy fields.

Seems like one-to-one relation mapping fits better for the functionality you required.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you want to create an user as a role, and a user **is not** a role, I think it fits more to say an **auditor is a role**(inheritance) and a **User has a role** (composition), so maybe you need to have the user common properties in one entity and the the role table is where you need to abstract your inheritance

Something like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User{

    //user properties 

    //Here is where you will share the user
    @optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user"
    private Role role

    // getters and setters
}
```

And here your role entity with will be the parent class

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Role implements Serializable {

    @SequenceGenerator(name = "ROLE_SEQ", sequenceName = "ROLE_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "ROLE_SEQ")
    @Id
    private Long idRole;
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private User user;
//getter and setters
```

}

and your specific role

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "auditor")
public class Auditor extends Role {
  // some properties
}
```

So in that way you can do something like this in java

```
  User user = new User();
 //set all the properties that you need for user or the reference for an existing user
  .
  .
  //Set the role that you need
    Auditor auditor = new Auditor();
    auditor.setUser(user);
    user.setRole(auditor);

    userDAO.insert(user);
```