# Creating missing subclass entity when super exists

Tags: java, hibernate, left-join, entity, hql

I have 2 tables **S** and **I** on the database (with a 1:1 relationship), they both have the same id as pk and the hibernate classes I've created are like these:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class S {
   @Id
   @Column(name = "id")
   @GeneratedValue(...)
   @SequenceGenerator...
   private long id;

   ....
}

@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
public class I extends S {
    ....
}
```

Because of historical reasons, in the database there are objects of type **S** but not the associated objects of type **I**. I want to create those **I** type objects using hibernate. How can I do that? Can I create an **I** type object  from an left join HQL query like this?

```
select i from I i right join i.id s where s.id = :id
```

If I try to create a new **I** entity (new I()) and then persist it, I only managed to get some exceptions as it tries to create an already existing **S** record. I can't do a simple read/load for **I** entity as **I** record does not exist yet. How can I do to create this missing **I** part entity?

*PS I will adjust the question if you point me the unclear things*

Comment: This is a similar situation as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038707/how-to-create-child-object-of-existing-super-object-using-joined-inheritance-st but I am interested in any means of solving that not only their approach ....

Answer (score 0):

One approach that will certainly work for you (while is isn't clean one) is to create I records with SQL inserts directly: `insert into I_table values (...)`.
When there are corresponding records in `I_table`, ORM will start load your objects with `I` type.

If you have to stay with your ORM and you can delete S records then you can

1. Load `S` by id
2. Delete `S` (flush? based on your flush mode)
3. Create `I`
4. Copy `S` values into `I`
5. Save `I`

Comment: This looks like a solution but the problem is that S is the root of a big entities tree and choosing this will mean copying a whole tree of entities to another, which will be cumbersome to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to create is an entity hierarchy. So have to map the entities correctly. The following is probably what you need:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.CHAR)
@DiscriminatorValue("S")
public class S {
   @Id
   //........
   private long id;

   ....
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("I")
public class I extends S {
    ....
}
```

- With this setting the table `S` will contain a column named `DTYPE` (for discriminator type) which identifies whether a row belongs to `S` or `I`; this is the default; if you don't want that you have to give a name for the `DiscriminatorColumn` annotation.
- Create an instance of `S` and save
- Create an instance of 'I' by populating the inherited properties (i.e., the properties of `S`) and its own properties, and save.
- When you create a query targeting `I`, you'll get only instances of `I`, but if your query targets the `S`, you'll get instances of both entities.